# How to create a masked image using blender python scripting in blender

Tags: python, scripting, masking

I am a beginner at blender. I have 5 cylinders present on the field in the shape of a plane, like this one:

[image]

I have 100 images in which the cylinder's shape and position are randomized. I want to create masked images for these 100 images. How can I do it?

I want to make the cylinders black and the field white. I need the script for this. I use Blender 3.6. I don't know which version is the most stable.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/119GOLnLHm-tOC8qaQGbqsMVIvXosclq4?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No scripting is required.

## Cycles

First set **pass index** for plane and cylinders. Let say field will be 1, cylinders will be 2:

[image]

On view layer tab enable **Object index**:

[image]

In compositor window enable use nodes:

[image]

Use ID mask node to get right mask (note 0 is background, 1 and 2 the objects that we just assigned):

[image]

You can save mask from image editor, or use file output node to save file automatically then the scene is rendered

[image]

## EEVEE (works with cycles also)

For EEVEE you can use cryptomatte pass instead. Enable cryptomatte pass in Layer tab:

[image]

Then in compositor window pass **pick** output of **cryptomatte** node in viewer (you have to enable backdrop feature to have picture at background):

[image]

Then click "+" icon and pick on plane (name of the object will be added)

[image]

Then you can use mate output to save as mask

[image]

Comment: Which version of blender you used? I have 2.93 and 3.6. The above process looks nice! I need to have a script for it. I want to do it for 100 images so I need the script :(

Comment: Set an animation with 100 frames, every frame will be saved by File Output node

Comment: I dont find an object index in my Blender version. is that the cryptomatte object one?

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is not supported in EEVEE. You can use cryptomatte instead.

Comment: @Blitz21Krieg I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out :)